# The numbers are erased in the table

Tags: tables, color

The numbers are erased when I color the cell, because how do I solve it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\begin{document}

    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}{V{4}p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
        \hlineB{3}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{blue!20}
        \multirow{2}{*}{1111}   & \multirow{2}{*}{222222} & \multicolumn{4}{V{1}cV{1}}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa}  \\
%       \hline
    %   \rowcolor{cyan}
    \cellcolor{blue!20}& \cellcolor{blue!20}& \cellcolor{cyan} 1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 \\
        \hline
    100&200 & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hline
    100&200 & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hlineB{4}
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position of the `multirow` to the last cell:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\begin{document}

    \begingroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.2}%
    \begin{tabular}{V{4}p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{25mm}|c|c|c|p{25mm}|c|c|cV{4}}
        \hlineB{3}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{blue!20}
    &  & \multicolumn{4}{V{1}cV{1}}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa}  \\
        %       \hline
        %   \rowcolor{cyan}
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!20} 1111}   & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!20}222222} & \cellcolor{cyan} 1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-1 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 & \cellcolor{cyan} 1e-2 \\
        \hline
        100&200 & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hline
        100&200 & 1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
        \hlineB{4}
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the line on the right-hand side looks too thin. Consider making it thinner by changing

```
&  & \multicolumn{4}{**V{1}cV{1}**}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa}  \\
```

to

```
&  & \multicolumn{4}{**cV{1}**}{aaaaa} & \multicolumn{4}{cV{4}}{aaaaa}  \\
```

[image: table with thinner line inside]

Comment: i edited my question with new example please help mee